# Spring Boot cannot see Aspect's

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop

maybe someone can help me with a little problem, so my application is starting, working perfectly etc. But, without aspect annotations (@After) declared to methods in service. I tried declaration thru annotation @HelloData via @annotation and path, also file path, and result is the same.

...

Benchmark.java

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Benchmark {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Benchmark.class);


    @Around("@annotation(HelloData)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("DADADADA!");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object out = joinPoint.proceed();
        long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        logTimeTaken(joinPoint, timeTaken);
        return out;
    }
    protected void logTimeTaken(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, long timeTaken) {
        System.out.println("DADADADA2!");
        log.info("..............................................................Time Taken by " + joinPoint + ": " + timeTaken);
    }
}
```

DataService.java [bottom]

```
@Service
public class DataService {
    private String fileName = "src/main/resources/MOCK_DATA.csv";

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataService.class);

    DataRepo dataRepo;
    DataSqlRepo dataSqlRepo;
    List<Data> list;
    List<DataSql> listTwo;

    //

    public DataService(final DataRepo dataRepo, final DataSqlRepo dataSqlRepo ) {
        this.dataRepo = dataRepo;
        this.dataSqlRepo = dataSqlRepo;
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        listTwo = new ArrayList<>();

        mapFile(fileName);
    }

    //

    public DataRepo getDataRepo() {
        return dataRepo;
    }

    public void setDataRepo(final DataRepo dataRepo) {
        this.dataRepo = dataRepo;
    }

    public DataSqlRepo getDataSqlRepo() {
        return dataSqlRepo;
    }

    public void setDataSqlRepo(final DataSqlRepo dataSqlRepo) {
        this.dataSqlRepo = dataSqlRepo;
    }

    public List<Data> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(final List<Data> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<DataSql> getListTwo() {
        return listTwo;
    }

    public void setListTwo(final List<DataSql> listTwo) {
        this.listTwo = listTwo;
    }


    //

    public void mapFile(String fileName){

        Map<String, String> mapping = new
                HashMap<String, String>();
        mapping.put("id", "id");
        mapping.put("first_name", "firstName");
        mapping.put("last_name", "lastName");
        mapping.put("email", "email");
        mapping.put("gender", "gender");
        mapping.put("ip_address", "ipAddress");


        HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Data> strategy =
                new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Data>();
        strategy.setType(Data.class);
        strategy.setColumnMapping(mapping);

        CSVReader csvReader = null;
        try {
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader
                    (fileName));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBean();


        list = csvToBean.parse(strategy, csvReader);



        for (Data e : list) {
            listTwo.add(new DataSql(Integer.parseInt(e.getId()),e.getFirstName(),e.getLastName(),e.getEmail(),e.getGender(),e.getIpAddress()));
        }

        saveToMongoDb(list);
        saveToSqlDb(listTwo);
    }

    @HelloData
    public void saveToMongoDb(List<Data> list) {
        logger.info("////");
        for (Data e : list) {
            dataRepo.save(e);
        }
        logger.info("////");
    }

    //

    @HelloData
    public void saveToSqlDb(List<DataSql> listTwo) {
        logger.info("//");
        for (DataSql f : listTwo) {
            dataSqlRepo.save(f);
        }
        logger.info("//");
    }
}
```

Console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-06-09 21:42:24.160  INFO 26000 --- [           main] c.e.csvtomongo.CsvToMongoApplication     : Starting CsvToMongoApplication on MSI with PID 26000 (C:\Users\Vetom\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\csv-to-mongo\target\classes started by Vetom in C:\Users\Vetom\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\csv-to-mongo)
2020-06-09 21:42:24.163  INFO 26000 --- [           main] c.e.csvtomongo.CsvToMongoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-09 21:42:24.710  INFO 26000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-06-09 21:42:24.711  INFO 26000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-06-09 21:42:24.740  INFO 26000 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.example.csvtomongo.model.DataRepo. If you want this repository to be a JPA repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: javax.persistence.Entity, javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.
2020-06-09 21:42:24.757  INFO 26000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 41ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-09 21:42:24.772  INFO 26000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-06-09 21:42:24.772  INFO 26000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-09 21:42:24.776  INFO 26000 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.example.csvtomongo.model.DataSqlRepo. If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository.
2020-06-09 21:42:24.778  INFO 26000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2020-06-09 21:42:25.284  INFO 26000 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-09 21:42:25.291  INFO 26000 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-09 21:42:25.291  INFO 26000 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-06-09 21:42:25.375  INFO 26000 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-09 21:42:25.375  INFO 26000 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1179 ms
2020-06-09 21:42:25.553  INFO 26000 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-09 21:42:25.589  INFO 26000 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-06-09 21:42:25.621  INFO 26000 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-06-09 21:42:25.689  INFO 26000 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2020-06-09 21:42:25.733  INFO 26000 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:254}] to localhost:27017
2020-06-09 21:42:25.736  INFO 26000 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2071700}
2020-06-09 21:42:25.744  INFO 26000 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-06-09 21:42:25.892  INFO 26000 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-09 21:42:25.980  INFO 26000 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-06-09 21:42:25.990  INFO 26000 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-06-09 21:42:26.465  INFO 26000 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-06-09 21:42:26.474  INFO 26000 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-09 21:42:26.805  INFO 26000 --- [           main] c.e.csvtomongo.service.DataService       : ////
2020-06-09 21:42:26.847  INFO 26000 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:255}] to localhost:27017
2020-06-09 21:42:27.334  INFO 26000 --- [           main] c.e.csvtomongo.service.DataService       : ////
2020-06-09 21:42:27.335  INFO 26000 --- [           main] c.e.csvtomongo.service.DataService       : //
2020-06-09 21:42:29.000  INFO 26000 --- [           main] c.e.csvtomongo.service.DataService       : //
2020-06-09 21:42:29.049  WARN 26000 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-06-09 21:42:29.665  INFO 26000 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-09 21:42:29.665  INFO 26000 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-06-09 21:42:29.666  INFO 26000 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-06-09 21:42:29.671  INFO 26000 --- [           main] c.e.csvtomongo.CsvToMongoApplication     : Started CsvToMongoApplication in 5.803 seconds (JVM running for 6.387)
```

Maybe someone do have any idea how to force this to work.

Comment: Your sample code is missing package and import information. Are you aware of the fact that if `HelloData` is not in the exact same package as the aspect, you need to use its fully qualified class name in the pointcut, e.g. `@annotation(my.package.name.HelloData)`? Furthermore, does the annotation have the correct `@Retention(RUNTIME)`? Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and try to always provide one. Thank you.

Comment: Also Spring AOP cannot intercept internal method calls. `DataService.mapFile()` calls `saveToSqlDb()` , this cannot be intercepted by Spring AOP. You may either move the `saveToSqlDb()` method to another bean or do a self autowiring of `DataService` bean to call the method.

Comment: Please read through [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) that starts with  *Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, calls within the target object are, by definition, not intercepted.*